# Why when updating the text in richTextBox it's starting from the bottom?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the constructor i'm adding lines to the richTextBox
Sub question: How can i make that in the end there will be no empty line in the bottom in the richTextBox ? The Environment.NewLine adding empty line in the end in the bottom.

```
foreach(string line in lines)
            {
                RichTextBoxExtensions.AppendText(richTextBox1, "Ready: ", Color.Red);
                richTextBox1.AppendText(line + Environment.NewLine);
            }

            foreach (string line in lines1)
            {
                RichTextBoxExtensions.AppendText(richTextBox1, "Ready: ", Color.Red);
                richTextBox1.AppendText(line + Environment.NewLine);
            }
```

Then in event i'm updating every line with part of the text:

```
private void downloader_Succeeded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RichTextBoxExtensions.UpdateText(richTextBox1, "Ready: ", "Downloaded: ", Color.Green);
        }
```

And the RichTextBoxExtensions class

```
public class RichTextBoxExtensions
        {
            public static void AppendText(RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
            {
                box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
                box.SelectionLength = 0;

                box.SelectionColor = color;
                box.AppendText(text);
                box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
            }
            public static void UpdateText(RichTextBox box, string find, string replace, Color? color)
            {
                box.SelectionStart = box.Find(find, RichTextBoxFinds.Reverse);
                box.SelectionLength = find.Length;
                box.SelectionColor = color ?? box.SelectionColor;
                box.SelectedText = replace;
            }
        }
```

The problem is when a file is downloaded and it's getting to the line:

```
RichTextBoxExtensions.UpdateText(richTextBox1, "Ready: ", "Downloaded: ", Color.Green);
```

It will update the text of the last line in the richTextBox in the bottom and will move up and update each line. But it should update from the top and to the bottom. I checked with a break point the downloads of the files start from the first link at the top to the bottom. So the problem is somewhere with the UpdateText.

Comment: It's because you are searching in reverse box.SelectionStart = box.Find(find, RichTextBoxFinds.Reverse);

Comment: @Mangist changed it to None and it's working now.

Comment: And how to solve the sub question ?

Comment: See my answer below please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `RichTextBoxFinds.Reverse` to `RichTextBoxFinds.None`

For your sub question, don't add a new line on the last line you append:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i ++)
    {
        RichTextBoxExtensions.AppendText(richTextBox1, "Ready: ", Color.Red);
        richTextBox1.AppendText(lines[i] + (i < lines.Count-1 ? Environment.NewLine : String.Empty));
    }
```